# Win32: How do I enumerate all the threads belonging to a process in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enumerating threads in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206878/enumerating-threads-in-windows)

I am trying to enumerate all threads belonging to a Win32 Window process.

I know I can get the process ID like so:

```
PDWORD procId;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, procId);
```

And I know that the whole thing can be done in C# like so:

```
// get process that owns the taskbar window
int procId;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out procId);

Process p = Process.GetProcessById(procId);
if (p != null)
{
    foreach (ProcessThread t in p.Threads)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

But as far as I can tell the Process class is a .NET class (please correct me if I'm wrong), and I'm trying my hardest to avoid .NET dependency. (Read: Please don't tell me to just use .NET.)

So the question is this: Is there a Win32 equivalent, given that I have correctly retrieved the PID?

(As a side note, I saw the [Tool Help Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686837%28VS.85%29.aspx) referenced in another question, but was not sure it was the best option. If it is, could you give a *brief* explanation/demonstration of how I would accomplish this or direct me to someone else's?)

As always, thanks immensely for all the help.

Comment: _sigh..._  It isn't an option. I'll simply leave it there.

Comment: 'twas a joke - "(Read: Please don't tell me to just use .NET.)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Thread Walking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686780%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [Enumerating threads in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206878/enumerating-threads-in-windows)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. These will help.