# How to obtain list of thread handles from a win32 process?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

Is it possible to get a list of thread handles at any given time for the current process on win32 (in c++)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will find [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/02/23/537856.aspx) helpful. It gives the code for thread enumeration with the small nuances that come with using the [tool help library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For convenience (lifted from the article):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 HANDLE h = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
 if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
  THREADENTRY32 te;
  te.dwSize = sizeof(te);
  if (Thread32First(h, &te)) {
   do {
     if (te.dwSize >= FIELD_OFFSET(THREADENTRY32, th32OwnerProcessID) +
                      sizeof(te.th32OwnerProcessID)) {
       printf("Process 0x%04x Thread 0x%04x\n",
             te.th32OwnerProcessID, te.th32ThreadID);
     }
   te.dwSize = sizeof(te);
   } while (Thread32Next(h, &te));
  }
  CloseHandle(h);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this gives you access to the ID of the threads, not the HANDLE as the requester asked.  There does not appear to be any API to get the HANDLE from the ID.  OpenThread on the ID returns an alternate HANDLE.

Comment: Just a heads up that the "toolhelp" API is **obnoxiously slow**... I would recommend calling `NtQuerySystemInformation` directly.

Answer (score 4):

- [Win32: How do I enumerate all the threads belonging to a process in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586545/win32-how-do-i-enumerate-all-the-threads-belonging-to-a-process-in-c)
- [`OpenThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684335%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert identifiers to handles

Comment: Just be aware that OpenThread returns an alternate HANDLE, not the original HANDLE.  It is useful for everything except comparing to the original handle.  And don't forget to CloseHandle when you are done with this alternate HANDLE.