# Find all threads of a process given process id

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, win32-process

I am trying to find if there is a better way to find all thread ids that belong to the current process. It looks like using CreateToolhelp32Snapshot with TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD and iterating over the threads to check if the thread's process id is equal to the current process id, is a solution but i want to avoid iterating all the running threads. I just want to iterate over the threads that belong to a given process. Please let me know if there is an API that is fast and simple. I need to do it in c++.

Thanks,
Abhinay.

Comment: Seems legit. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/02/23/537856.aspx

Comment: Premature optimization, a machine doesn't usually have more than 1000 active threads.  You could use TH32CS_SNAPALL to make it selective on *th32ProcessID*.

Comment: @Hans: TH32CS_SNAPALL is described as "Includes all processes and threads in the system, plus the heaps and modules of the process specified in th32ProcessID" - so it will not help.

Comment: The .Net Process class has a Threads property, but it seems to grab a snapshot of all processes and threads from HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA, and then returns just the information for the current process.  As you've noted, Toolhelp also grabs a snapshot of everything (and is less of a pain to use than performance data).  psapi doesn't handle threads at all.  I suspect you're out of luck.  If you just need a thread list for your own process add a DLL whose DllMain will get notified when threads are created or destroyed.

Comment: As far I know exist two another approaches using the [`Performance Data Helper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa939698%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx) (but you need to filter by the PID too ) or  using the [`Win32_Thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI Class filtering by the `ProcessHandle` property but the speed of the WMI in this case is not comparable to the WinAPI. So my advice is keep using the CreateToolhelp32Snapshot function.

Comment: Check these two out: [Thread Walking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686780(v=VS.85).aspx), [Enumerating Threads in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206878/enumerating-threads-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

If the "current process" is one you've written, you can take advantage of the fact that DllMain functions get called any time a thread is added or terminated with reason codes of DLL_THREAD_ATTACH and DLL_THREAD_DETACH.  It's simple to then keep your own list.

Answer (score 0):

After using CreateToolhelp32Snapshot with TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS (0x00000002), you can get thread by using [Thread32First function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Example code is [here](http://www.codeexperts.com/showthread.php?565-How-to-get-threads-of-current-process&s=3132d31ef0d200d4d57b3858ee678de0&p=1165&viewfull=1#post1165).