# How to get all thread Handle list that are created using single process in VC++?

Tags: windows, visual-c++

Everybody

First I created Single process.
After creates many threads that belongs to single process.

How to get all thread list that are belongs to single process?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206878/enumerating-threads-in-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Tool Help Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). And there are a few examples of how to use it.